# haproxy bind multiple ports for https forwarding

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy

I'am trying to forward 2 https ports to 2 different destinations but the haproxy service fails to start. When i use simple http all is ok. Does Haproxy support 2 https ports or something am doing wrong?. Below is my haproxy configuration for this.

```
frontend https1
   bind  *:9444 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/server.pem
   mode http
   use_backend bk1_https

frontend https2
   bind  *:9443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/server2.pem
   mode http
   use_backend bk2_https


backend bk1_https
   balance first
   server server1 IP1:9444 check ssl verify none

backend bk2_https
   balance first
   server server1 Ip1:9443 check ssl verify none
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full output of HAProxy when it attempts to start and fails. Usually, it contains pretty straight-forward reasons.

Comment: Doesn' t give any good output, just says that failed the service to start......

Comment: You can run `haproxy -c -f /path/to/your/haproxy.cfg`. HAProxy will check your config and will detect almost all issues with it even without starting the actual service. Please edit your question and include at least this data.